# Pass parameter containing `&` with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am passing my string to PHP through AJAX using `$.Ajax`.

I'm trying to pass this string:

```
action=abc&parameter=C&W
```

The AJAX splits the `C&W` on the basis of `&`, so the request comes in this format:

```
$action = "abc";
$parameter = "C";
```

How can I pass it as `C&W`, without it being split into a different parameter?

Comment: @Pranav No you need `action=abc&parameter=C%26W`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should let jQuery do the encoding for you :

```
$.ajax({
   url: someUrl, // <- no parameter here
   data: {action:'abc', parameter:'C&W'},
   ...
```

Comment: @copticbag should be automatic

Comment: The URL will be properly encoded, which means that any standard server will read it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using bog-standard JavaScript (no jQuery), you can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1563422):

```
var url = "action=" + encodeURIComponent(action) + "&parameter=" + encodeURIComponent(param);
```

Comment: jQuery is used anyways, so why compose the URL yourself? This makes sense if you used `XmlHttpRequest`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ah, no jQuery tag. Just spotted the elusive `$.Ajax` in the question body.